# Behaviour of VTOR register on STM32H7 at reset

Tags: arm, stm32, boot

The Vector Table offset register on a Cortex M7 allows to relocate the Vector Table.

I am wondering how the Vector Table is managed when it is relocated and a soft reset occurs.

The ARM programming manual mentions that the value of VTOR after reset is "unknown".

What reset handler is used after a soft reset: the "original" one from the vector table in Flash ? Or the "relocated" one set through VTOR ?

Same question for the Stack Pointer. The Programming manual states that "On reset, the processor loads the MSP with the value from address 0x00000000". Does that mean that the Stack Pointer in a relocated Vector Table is never used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean that the Stack Pointer in a relocated Vector Table is
>   never used ?

It is not used by the hardware. It is used by bootloader when launching the application.

> What reset handler is used after a soft reset: the "original" one from
>   the vector table in Flash

The one selected by the boot pins & boot option bytes.

> The ARM programming manual mentions that the value of VTOR after reset
>   is "unknown".

I do not think so, my programming manual shows:
[image]
Which is quite well defined :)

> I am wondering how the Vector Table is managed when it is relocated
>   and a soft reset occurs.

Same as during the hardware reset.

Comment: Thank you. What precise document are you referring to ? I checked on the STM32H7 programming manual and I confirm it says "unknown value at reset". Also it is not entirely true: at reset (first instruction of reset handler) of a STM32H743, VTOR is 0x0800 0000 which obviously makes sense since 0x0000 0000 points to RAM.

Comment: Well not the programming manual provided by ST and referenced PM0253. perhaps a doc from ARM ?

Comment: I would avoid the "programming manuals" from arm or other, the rare time I look at one I find problems/errors with it.  use the technical reference manual for the core you are using (and rev) and from that the architectural reference manual.  the programming manuals (from arm) are not of the same quality or accuracy as the others, and are in places somewhat disturbing.

Comment: if vtor is used to find the vectors then it cant possibly be unknown otherwise you wouldnt be able to boot reliably, so either it is unknown and there is an exception for the reset (vector), or it is known (and zero).

Comment: You are welcome to experiment, but yes the sp init value (and the reset vector) are likely not used in a relocated table.  A reset is a reset to the arm core, what the chip vendor has mapped that address space to is a chip vendor thing and independent, the arm core fetches from a known address on reset, unless the arm core has a soft/partial reset and in that case the exceptions would be documented either in the arm arm or the arm trm

Comment: vendors like ST have for some parts provided a programming manual that was what appeared to me to be an illegal reproduction of the arm arm or arm trm for that core.  now arm has this notion of a programming manual and I avoid them like the plague as I see to many questions/problems like this.

Comment: so it is possible that vtor is not used on reset and the sp and reset vector are at the known fixed addresses, so technically it is possible that vtor could be random garbage.  But I have not experienced that when I look at it, and documents as shown in this answer would also indicate that it does have a known reset value (even if it isnt used by reset itself).